# Convert Bigger SQL into Multiple Smaller SQLs combined by UNION ALL

Tags: java, sql, presto

I have a sample SQL Like

```
SELECT id, age, department
FROM User
WHERE
age < 50 AND id > 100 AND
(
  department = 'IT' OR department = 'DEVOPS' OR department = 'ACCOUNTING' .... more OR conditions on department
)
```

**I need to convert this SQL into multiple SQLs which are combined by UNION ALL (wherein the original logic is retained).**

The desired result is

```
(
  SELECT id, age, department
  FROM User
  WHERE age < 50 AND id > 100 AND department = 'IT'
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT id, age, department
  FROM User
  WHERE age < 50 AND id > 100 AND department = 'DEVOPS'
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT id, age, department
  FROM User
  WHERE age < 50 AND id > 100 AND department = 'ACCOUNTING'
)
UNION ALL
....further conditions
```

**Bit background**

we are using PRESTO DB as SQL engine.
We found 1 limitation wherein if query is large and has more than 1000 AND/OR conditions, it fails.
One of the solution is to reduce conditions via UNION.
https://support.treasuredata.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001457447-Presto-Query-FAQs

Can this be achieved programatically by using SQL parser libraries?

Comment: Why do you want to use `UNION ALL` for this?

Comment: It is not a good idea to do this. Time taken to execute your UNION ALL queries will be huge.

Comment: We are using PRESTO DB as SQL engine. We found 1 limitation wherein if query is large and has more than 1000 AND/OR conditions, it fails. One of the solution is to reduce conditions via UNION.

The above query is an imitation of the actual query we use (which is more complex)

Comment: How do you build your sample SQL, i.e. the one without the UNION ALL?

Comment: Can you please share the exception message @hemantvsn

Comment: @AnkitDixit https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/9039

Comment: Put the DEVOPS, ACCOUNTING etc values in a separate (temporary?) table. JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Use `in` and a `not between`

```
select *
from myTable
where department in ('IT', 'Finance', 'etc')
and not age between 50 and 100
```

Comment: I think the question was more about how to do it automatically, not what construction to use. OPs query has over 1000 AND/ORs so doing that manually would be tiresome.

Comment: Sorry, but its not what Im looking for.
As I mentioned, the actual query is quite complex. Hence replacement with IN is not possible